# Connecting Memcach Servers

Tags: java, memory-management, memcached

I want to know how to configure Memcache server to accept request which come from given IP addresses only. Can I do it with iptables rules ? Any sample codes are highy appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use ip-tables for the same,

Start memcached using something like this:

`/usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -l 0.0.0.0 -d -u www-data -m 12288`

In the above command, `-l` parameter is set to `0.0.0.0`, which allows connections from ANY source. If you keep the standard `127.0.0.1` this will not work.

Next, we make entries to the iptables. If your memcached server is on your LAN, the following command will allow connections only from specific local servers.

For instance, in order to add `192.168.4.25` to the allowed list, we issue the command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.4.24 --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want to whitelist a remote server, for example, `25.62.25.62` then you issue another command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 25.62.25.62 --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
```

You can whitelist as many IPs as you want, but be sure to issue the final command that blocks all other connections on that port.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -j REJECT
```

The IPtables are read in the order they are entered, so if you issue a REJECT ALL statement before issuing any ACCEPT rules, all connections will be rejected (even the whitelisted ones).